# OnChange Event not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a textbox for which the value is loaded through a modal form. Everytime the text changes, I want the OnChange event to trigger and enable a button. My OnChange event does not seem to fire. My Javascript and the code is given below:

```
$("#txtFileName").change(function () {
    var selectedvalue = $("#FileGuid").val();
    alert(selectedvalue);           
});

<div class="editor-field modFileLoad">
  <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FileGuid, new { @class = "flGuid",Visible=false })>
  <%: Html.TextBoxFor_Readonly(model => model.FileName, new{id= "txtFileName",style    = "width:400px;", @class = "flName" })%>  
</div>
```

Comment: change only fires when focus moves away from the textbox, I think you need to capture keyEvents

Comment: Use `.keyUp()` event instead of `.change()` event

Comment: @AnkurMittal: unfortunately the user is not typing in the text box to capture the keyevents, the values will be populated through a modal form

Comment: @sansid: Did you tried `.blur()` instead of `.change()` ?

Comment: @A.K yes tried .blur() with no success. Does it have anything to do with the fact that it is a ReadOnly text box?

Comment: @sansid: `.blur()` is [working here](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/SGBVC/)

Comment: @A.K Thank you for the link. But, it works only when I click on the text box and move away from it, in my case, it has to trigger automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.keyUp()` event instead of `.change()` event.

`.change()` only fires when focus moves out from an element.

Example:

```
$("#txtFileName").keyUp(function () {
    var selectedvalue = $("#FileGuid").val();
    alert(selectedvalue);           
});
```